# Plugin Dev - Keeping Track of Windows inside a single Tab

Tags: vimscript, vim-windows, plugin-development

I'm trying to build a new plugin and I got myself a question about managing multiple **windows** inside a single **tab** (hope the terms are correct).

So far the examples and projects I've explored trying to get a grasp of what I would call **window life-cycle** did not clarified how can one keep track of multiple ones.

The effect I'm trying to replicate is:

> User will be presented with 4 windows (splits)

```
+---+---+
| 1 | 2 |
+---+---+
| 3 | 4 |
+---+---+
```

> The "window 1" would present a list of entries and whatever line the User presses  the other windows how render different data/information

Based on that the question is:
Do we have a mechanism to associate a "nickname"/label a window? Maybe a number reference? **OR** we would track/distinct window based solely on their position placed on the tab?

Comment: see `:help winid`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thank you. That's what I was missing. Appreciate the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All windows have a distinct `:help winid` that can be used with various functions.